# Gatsby queries error with multiple queries error

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm starting a personal blog made in gatsby.

when I make a graphql query, I receive the error:

**"Multiple "root" queries found: "articlesListUnique" and "articlesListUnique"**

```js
export const query = graphql`
query articlesListUnique{
    allMarkdownRemark {
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          date
          slug
          subtitle
          title
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
  
`
```

I'm still building the site, and this is the first and only graphql query in all project.
so it's not possible to be duplicate query names.

when I remove the name of the query, its starts to work, but send me back this error code:

```
warn The GraphQL query in the non-page component 
"D:/Andre/Material/Projetos/Homesite/myhome/myhome/src/pages/articles.js" will not be run.
Exported queries are only executed for Page components. It's possible you're
trying to create pages in your gatsby-node.js and that's failing for some
reason.

If the failing component(s) is a regular component and not intended to be a page
component, you generally want to use a <StaticQuery> (https://gatsbyjs.com/docs/static-query)
instead of exporting a page query.

If you're more experienced with GraphQL, you can also export GraphQL
fragments from components and compose the fragments in the Page component
query and pass data down into the child component — https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments
```

This is my gatsby-config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `content`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/content/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: Hi @FerranBuireu,
I, uptaded the question with my gatsby config file.